# OnEdit code stopped working without any changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I wrote the code below about a month ago.  All it does it highlight the row when the checkbox is checked and clears it when unchecked.  It was working fine, now it's not and I did not change anything.

In the executions section I can see it failing with:

> Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
> at onEdit(Code:43:55)

and

> Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.
> at onEdit(Code:44:56)

Clearly it thinks that the variable "editRow" is a string but I have no idea why it does now and didn't before.  `43:55` and `44:56` are the if statements for TRUE and FALSE, this code is clipped from all the rest (other things not relivant).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1")
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();var editRow = e.range.rowStart;var editColumn = e.range.columnStart;var editValue = e.value;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();var formResponses = sheet.getSheetByName ("Form Responses 1");

  if(ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Form Responses 1"){}
  else{return};
 
  if (editValue == "TRUE" && editColumn == 20) {sheet.getRange(editRow,1,1,21).setBackground("yellow")};
  if (editValue == "FALSE" && editColumn == 20) {sheet.getRange(editRow,1,1,21).setBackground(null)};
}
```

Comment: Please organize your code with one command per line

Comment: It looks to me like you are attempting to use code written for an onEdit trigger with a form submit trigger and on edit triggers are not generated for form submits.  So that's not going to work.

Comment: It's a matter of style / opinion: Variables like `var editRow = e.range.rowStart;` doesn't really make the code better, just make it "verbose" (longer)

Comment: This is a separate function from the form submit.  Again, this code was working perfect up until about 2 days ago.  No changes were made.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages says that `e.range.rowStart` and `e.range.columnStart` are returning a string rather than a number. That string might occurr, among other possibilities, if they are `undefined` i.e. because onEdit is triggered by something that provides a range property but that hasn't `rowStart` and `columnStart` properties.

Add `console.log(JSON.stringify(e));` after `function onEdit(e){` so you could see in the logs the values properties of  `e`.

Comment: I used a pop up message and the correct row number was showing up, so it's returning correctly, unless it's a string

Comment: Sorry just got back to work, been super sick.  I added that after onEdit, where would I find what is returned?

Comment: I tried using this instead, still not working

var range = e.range;
var editRow = range.getRow();

Comment: I have been playing around with this more now that I am back and have time.

I manually set the row number vs trying to use a variable:

  if (editValue == "TRUE" && editColumn == 20) {sheet.getRange(131,1,1,21).setBackground("yellow")};
  if (editValue == "FALSE" && editColumn == 20) {sheet.getRange(131,1,1,21).setBackground(null)};

I get the same exact error.  That means the variable being a string is not the issue?  The row start and end are the correct row and the row number that I manually entered in the code.

https://ibb.co/s5JXPXQ

Answer (score 0):

I started commenting out lines that did other things in the onEdit function.  I narrowed it down to these lines that set variables for an email that is sent.  It does not edit any of the already established variables, just makes new ones.

I do not understand why commenting these lines out  allows it to work but it does.  I was able to move them to below the lines that were erroring out and it's working again.

```
  var recipient = formResponses.getRange("E"+editRow).getValue();
  var subject = "Chromebook " + formResponses.getRange("B"+editRow).getValue() + " was marked as returned";
  if (formResponses.getRange("H"+editRow).getValue() === ''){
    var body = "Chromebook " + formResponses.getRange("B"+editRow).getValue() + " was marked as returned.  Action taken: Returned from //ITSavvy"
  }
  else{var body = "Chromebook " + formResponses.getRange("B"+editRow).getValue() + " was marked at returned.  Action taken: " + formResponses.getRange("H"+editRow).getValue()};
```